# what is the right way to scan/search for words within file, on RHEL (Gnu/Linux)

Tags: linux, grep, filesystems, rhel

We want to scan for words on our Gnu/Linux machine.
A simple way is for example with `grep`

```
grep -r "some_word" /var
```

However in the case we want to scan the whole filesystem, then we can't do just `grep -r "some_word" /`, because it is scan the files in `/proc`, (these should be exclude).
Therefore I want to know if there are some useful tools to scan for this purpose ?

I know in gnu `grep` - we have the option of `--exclude-dir`, but I still want to know a better way for searching words on Gnu/Linux file-system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find / -path /sys -prune -o -path /proc -prune -o -type f -exec grep -r "some_word" {} \;
```

I believe this is what you want

Comment: If you're using `find` there's no need to specify `grep -r`; just use `grep`

Answer (score 2):

The `find` utility can be made to stay within a single filesystem if you use it with its `-xdev` option.  This means that the command

```bsh
find / -xdev -type f -exec grep -w -F 'word' {} +
```

... would stay within the root filesystem and not wander off into `/sys` or `/proc`.

In the root filesystem, it would pass batches of file pathnames to `grep` to look for the word `word`.

If you have other filesystems mounted that you want to search too, then just list them as top-level search paths.  For example, if `/home` and `/tank` are partitions mounted separately, and you want to search them,

```bsh
find / /home /tank -xdev -type f -exec grep -w -F 'word' {} +
```

The `-xdev` predicate is standard and should be available with most, if not all, implementations of `find`.